# Multiple sub-agents for one table in Net-SNMP

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, mib, snmpd

I'm writing a custom MIB to expose a table over SNMP. There will be one table with set columns, but a variable numbers of rows. Is it possible, with `Net-SNMP`, to add multiple rows to the table from multiple processes (e.g. process A creates row 1, process B creates row 2, etc...)? I would like to avoid having one "master sub-agent" if possible (other then something that is a part of `Net-SNMP`, like `snmpd`/`snmptrapd`/etc).

I would like to use `mib2c` to help generate code if possible, but I can work around that if it can't accomplish what I need.

I'm using `Net-SNMP 5.5` at the moment. Upgrading is possible if support for what I need is added in newer versions.

Comment: FWIW, and this doesn't really help you, when implementing my agent with all its various complex tables, I just did so myself in C++ and borrowed only Net-SNMP's PDU building and transport code. Getting table traversal to work with all the combinations of what _GetNext_ does wasn't exactly trivial, but the end result is highly extensible and "adding a row" is now as simple as appending to a C++ vector. Anecdote over

Comment: (I guess my point is that you needn't necessarily restrict yourself to what Net-SNMP can do for you out of the box.)

Comment: Right - I did recently run in to the GetNext issue. I certainly could just build my own PDU's, but before I go the route of essentially maintaining my own SNMP stack, I'd probably rather look at other SNMP libraries like agent++. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

If writing AgentX for snmpd, it looks like you cannot share the table OID over two or more AgentXs, snmpd responds with an error that oid is a duplicate for some of the sub-agents.  Thus I am continuing my sources with my own sub-sub-agents (based on Enduro/X) which collect the data into a single AgentX which would fill the SNMP table.

According to the https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2741.html#section-7.1.4.1 :

> 7.1.4.1.  Handling Duplicate and Overlapping Subtrees
>
> As a result of this registration algorithm there are likely to be
> duplicate and/or overlapping subtrees within the registration data
> store of the master agent.  Whenever the master agent's dispatching
> algorithm (see section 7.2.1, "Dispatching AgentX PDUs") determines
> that there are multiple subtrees that could potentially contain the
> same MIB object instances, the master agent selects one to use,
> termed the 'authoritative region', as follows:
>
> ```
>  1) Choose the one whose original agentx-Register-PDU r.subtree
>     contained the most subids, i.e., the most specific r.subtree.
>     Note: The presence or absence of a range subid has no bearing
>     on how "specific" one object identifier is compared to another.
>
>  2) If still ambiguous, there were duplicate subtrees.  Choose the
>     one whose original agentx-Register-PDU specified the smaller
>     value of r.priority.
> ```

So in best case scenario, you might get that data is randomly collected from one AgentX or another, if the same oid is registered from different AgentX processes